Google sign in libgdx
I have issues with json file given by Google cloud console the Google give the client id .json file but chat gpt recommend Google services.json file
I have now API Exception 12500
In my code after click the button ,the Google Gmail accounts tap open but I click the Gmail account API Exception coming

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
